# What types of inconsistency are there that we know of?

Tags: reference-request, types, paraconsistency

Just trying to verify consistency of a system, I need to have a list types of inconsistency to look out for, so far I have the followings:

1.Anachronistic inconsistency (e.g. trying to read a file before it is been written).

2.Type inconsistency (e.g. treating an object as a type that is incompatible with the assumed type, e.g. treating lead as steel is
    inconsistent (lead can not replace still in all the contexts), but
    treating lead and steel as metal is consistent. (where ever lead or
    steel is used just as a metal they are interchangeable)).

3.Interface inconsistency : Trying to interact with an object through an interface that it does not support ( e.g. trying to plug
    in a charger designed for electrical outlets of Australia, in US ).
    How ever if we could even plug them in, the difference in
    voltage(?current) would blow up the charger due to type
    inconsistency ( can not treat electrical US electrical current same
    as Australian electrical current or vice verse)

4.Causal Consistency : Maybe this is same as Anachronistic inconsistency, e.g. a Glass cannot break midair before it hits the
    floor. Although the after effects of both are indistinguishable from
    the consistent version, there is an inconsistency in mid process.

I have tried googling, but [Physical paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_paradox) was the only useful topic so far when googling : "list of physical inconsistencies".

Any alternative searches or topics to look up would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I think you are going to run into a problem that you are looking for a particular taxonomy of inconsistencies which maps to your particular task.  I would not be surprised if there are thousands of named types of inconsistencies in philosophy, but you need them in a taxonomy which is helpful to you.  Given your choice of programmer verbiage, might this be better suited for programmer SE?

Comment: @CortAmmon : Thank you, I be happy with any taxonomy of inconsistencies, although I grabbed a problem from programming, I am more interested in philosophical inconsistencies. I highly doubt that programmers have even pondered about listing inconsistencies in programming let alone classify them.

Answer (score 1):

There is are a number of books by [Graham Priest](http://grahampriest.net) on this; the general term is [dialethism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/): the proposition that there are true contradictions.

Comment: I am sorry, I can not see how does this relates to my question. I like this concept, taught me a new concept +1.

Comment: @arjang: you might want to take a closer look at Cort Ammons comment; the kinds of inconsistency you're discussing in your question aren't philosophical types of inconsistency

Comment: I dont know more I can do with Cort Ammons comment, I am open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, your notion of 'inconsistency', say for your first point, the 'anachronistic inconsistency' appears to be relying on the ordinary language use; in this case it just means doing things out of order in time; but this can go for many things; in which case the closest analogy I can think of is knowing how to use a tool well; it's a form of practical knowledge; not knowing how to use a tool well isn't inconsistency, merely lack of practical knowledge.

Comment: But this is the philosophical explanation - it won't help you verify 'consistency in a system'; that's a purely practical problem that in this case is domain-specific ie to Software Development.

Comment: That could also be changed with the law of causality, things happening out of order in reality break the consistency of reality.

Comment: Which is why you were referred to programmers.SE.

Comment: @Arjang: in Christian philosophy that would be called a 'miracle'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26513/discussion-between-mozibur-ullah-and-arjang).

Comment: Because there must be a list that ant philosophical theory can be held against. List of all that would not make the theory inconsistent, or is there no such test for verification of philosophical theories?